# What does Copy-edited. mean?

Tags: support

In the Comment Summary box, recently I have been seeing ([example](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/378377)) "*Copy-edited.*".

What does this phrase mean? Or is it just people not bothering to write anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means general changes to spelling punctuation and capitalization, without changing the order or adding text. Which is what he did.

[Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_editing)

Comment: Well done @muru :p!